# NativeScript | Can't run Android app: Please fix the version conflict either by updating version 11.4.0 of the google-services plugin

Tags: nativescript, native, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the  
google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at   
https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)  
or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.4.0.
```

Comment: You must be using two or more plugins that uses different versions of Google Play Services, check the ReadMe of the plugin there must be a simple solution. Let's know what plugins you use.

Comment: using  here  googlePlayServicesVersion = "11.4.0"
     firebaseMessagingVersion = "11.4.0" but getting same error

Comment: using plugin here : Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-angular for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-barcodescanner for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-bluetooth for android.

Comment: Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-camera for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-contacts for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-directions for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-email for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-fancy-geo for android.

Comment: nativescript-geocoding 5.2.0 for android is not compatible with the currently installed framework version 5.1.0.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-geocoding for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-geolocation for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-mapbox for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-messenger for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-phone for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-push-notifications for android.

Comment: Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-sms-inbox for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-telephony for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-theme-core for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-ui-calendar for android.
Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-intl for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-permissions for android.

Comment: Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-appavailability for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-ui-core for android.
Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules-widgets for android.

Comment: is it fixed for you now? can you share your package.json?